# Can I alter the RestTemplate used in Spring's ProxyExchange?

Tags: spring-mvc, resttemplate

I'm using Spring's `ProxyExchange`, and I want to change the default `RestTemplate` (in order to ignore certificates on dev env).

Is there a way to do that?

Using MVC (and not flux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I built a `RestTemplateCustomizer` and added a bean to customize the default `RestTemplate`

Answer (score 2):

We altered RestTemplate using ProxyExchangeArgumentResolver class. below is code snippet

```
package com.vikrant.practice.config;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.mvc.config.ProxyExchangeArgumentResolver;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.mvc.config.ProxyProperties;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.mvc.config.ProxyResponseAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.Optional;


@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.vikrant.practice"})
public class XyzConfig {

    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setSocketTimeout(30000).setConnectTimeout(30000).build();

        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(100);
        poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(100);

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder
                .create().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                .setConnectionManager(poolingHttpClientConnectionManager)
                .disableCookieManagement().build();

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        factory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(1000);
        factory.setReadTimeout(30000);
        factory.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        factory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);
        return restTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProxyExchangeArgumentResolver proxyExchangeArgumentResolver(
            Optional<RestTemplateBuilder> optional, ProxyProperties proxy) {
        RestTemplate template = restTemplate();
        template.getMessageConverters().add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter() {
            @Override
            public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        ProxyExchangeArgumentResolver resolver = new ProxyExchangeArgumentResolver(template);
        resolver.setHeaders(proxy.convertHeaders());
        resolver.setSensitive(proxy.getSensitive());
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

This was done for SpringBoot application. In case you want to use it in web application then create a class extending SpringBootServletInitializer and implementing  WebApplicationInitializer and in that under configure method wire this class.